# Need some code to change text by visitor country

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple website offering some services (coding with html, css, js, php), i want to change text of my button by visitor country.

For example if the visitor is from Europe text change to : 100 euro
and if the visitor is from America text change to : 100 Dollars.

```html
        <div class="pricing-cont">
          <h5>Professionnel</h5>
          <h2><small>From </small><br>100 </h2>
      </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried something or is that a request?

Comment: Look into currency "localization".

Comment: You're just changing the currencies without converting them? What a rip-off

Comment: 100 euros are worth more than 100 dollars (at the time of writing). This approach is either childishly naive or deliberately designed to overcharge (although that idea could easily backfire if you convert 100 dollars to 100 Indian rupees, for example!). Do you understand about exchange rates?

Comment: ...Or is this just a ridiculously oversimplified example? I know the guidance asks you to create a minimal example, but generally not at the expense of presenting a realistic scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a IP to location service like [MaxMind](https://www.maxmind.com/en/home), it gets the users IP and returns the users country, It's accurate most of the time and is easy to use. MaxMind already has a JavaScript api, you can find the documentation [here](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/).

**Implementation**

HTML:

```html
<div class="pricing-cont">
  <h5>Professionnel</h5>
  <h2 id="priceEl"><small>From </small><br>100 </h2>
</div>
<script src="//js.maxmind.com/js/apis/geoip2/v2.1/geoip2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="yourscript.js"></script>
```

JavaScript(yourcript.js):

```
var price = document.getElementById('priceEl');

var onSuccess = function(country) {
  var countryy = country.iso_code;
  if (countryy === "US") {
    price.innerHTML = "<small>From </small><br> 100 Dollars"
  }
  if (countryy === "CN") {
    price.innerHTML = "<small>From </small><br> 100 Renminbi"
  } // etc
  // When including a lot of cases a switch statement is better practice
};
var onError = function(error) {
  console.error("Error:\n\n" + error.code + " " + error.error);
};

geoip2.city(onSuccess, onError);
```

However for this to work you will need to create a MaxMind account and register the domain that you are going to be using the MaxMind api on.